# sending e-commerce tracking via phonegap app

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, cordova-3

i am trying to send e-commerce tracking (Universal Analytics) info from a phonegap app.

I have got the gaplugin working, sending event tracking, but the plugin doesn't support ecommerce tracking

So I've got it working pluginless for events, but it doesn't seem to work for e-commerce tracking.

```
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '1234',
    // Transaction ID. Required.
    'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',
    // Affiliation or store name.
    'revenue': '11.99',
    // Grand Total.
    'shipping': '5',
    // Shipping.
    'tax': '1.29',
    // Tax.
    'currency': 'EUR'
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

is the code I am using

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record the project that I was working on forked the GAPlugin and added e-commerce tracking for both android and ios, here:

https://github.com/neilrackett/phonegap-ga-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're missing the `ecommerce:addItem` command:

```
// loads ecommerce plugin
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

// adds transaction data
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
  'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
});

// adds item data
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
  'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
  'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});

// sends transaction
ga('ecommerce:send');
```

More info in Google's documentation : [Ecommerce Tracking - Web Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce)

Comment: I didn't think it was needed: "['ecommerce:send'] will go through each transaction and item in the shopping cart and send the respective data to Google Analytics". Infact I have got this working in the browser, without adding items. It just fails in phonegap